# Darlington as CB

Tags: transistors, bjt, darlington

1. Why do we use Darlington pair?
2. I've heard that we don't use it as common base. Why is that?
3. Why don't we just develop a BJT with high beta value istead of using this structure?
4. What are the different types of it?
5. How can I recognize the emitter and collector of it (for example in the image below)?

[image]

Comment: They do make superbeta >1k,  transistors but cost $$

Comment: This is a quasi Darlington by another name. Can you find it?

Comment: Neither of your diagrams shows a Darlington Pair.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complementary_feedback_pair

Comment: This is superbeta connection, not darlington. Hint: darlington contains 2 (or more) transistors of the same polarity, and all collectors are connected together.

Comment: There is a base in the pictures above. Why don't make it "common"? What does this mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. For high current loads. BJTs are a current-controlled device, so one might not provide enough current amplification. This is called the beta value and is normally around 100-300 for general purpose transistors
2. The base current is being amplified and projected through the collector to the emitter (in NPN). If it's common base, the current is the same through both transistors. Stacking the base of the second transistor to the emitter of the first one provides amplification in the 1000s
3. Good point, these are expensive! Alternatives are [MOSFETs](https://youtu.be/GrvvkYTW_0k) which are voltage controlled and can handle high currents.
4. NPN, PNP and Szikial pair [(push pull amplifier)](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/transistor/darlington-transistor.html)
5. These are generally labelled in Darlington ICs such as the [ULN2003](https://cpc.farnell.com/stmicroelectronics/uln2003a/darlington-array-7npn-2003-dip16/dp/SC08601?mckv=seraAM1oo_dm%7Cpcrid%7C382877336594%7Ckword%7C%7Cmatch%7C%7Cplid%7C%7Cslid%7C%7Cproduct%7CSC08601%7Cpgrid%7C81075586787%7Cptaid%7Cpla-294505072980%7C&CMP=KNC-GUK-CPC-SHOPPING&gclid=CjwKCAiA6bvwBRBbEiwAUER6JbugGKfZd4p8p_ciLXjR3yPdQ6Y2vRI_AHlX6rBcKjRJ_udDk-DNmRoClgsQAvD_BwE)

Comment: ...."enough current amplification"??? Michael J,, please, can you explain WHY you think that "current amplification" is such a critical parameter? For my knowledge (as shown in my contribution), the only point is: Input resistance. Nothing else. Otherwise, a single high-current BJT could do the job.

Comment: @LvW I have never been a fan of the term "dynamic input resistance" when talking about a BJT. It gives students the false impression that one can model the base behavior as a resistance - this is only true over a *very* narrow range of base voltages, since the I-V relation for the base current is exponential WRT to voltage (hence, "dynamic" resistance). It is much more useful to think of the BJT base as representing a forward biased diode connected to the emitter, which nicely captures the fact that above around 0.7 V the "resistance" is basically negligible.

Comment: @LvW As for why current gain is a figure of merit - simple, whatever is actually *driving* the transistor is going to have some limitation on its ability to source current. For example, a typical microcontroller GPIO pin is only going to be able to source a few milliamps maximum. If you can source 5 mA and you need to drive 2 A, you know that you need an "effective" h_FE of around 400. So, you just go and find two transistors such that their minimum h_FEs multiplied together is >400. That's a lot simpler than the dynamic resistance viewpoint.

Comment: @Peter..I cannot agree at all and I do not understand your reasoning.. As shown in my numeric example, the signal input resistance of a single transistor at the base may be in the range of some kohms only - and you suggest to neglect it? That means - to assume that the input resistance is infinite? What do you think is the reason the Darlington transistor was introduced? Is there any other motivation than the signal input resistance at the base node?

Comment: @LvW I am suggesting that for intuition's sake you assume the input impedance at the base is essentially zero (not infinity) when V_be > 0.7V in forward active mode. This builds a more useful intuition of the BJT as a "current amplifier" rather than going through the rigmarole of trying to derive expressions that let us treat the BJT as a transimpedance amplifier. Under this viewpoint, it's easy to see that the purpose of the Darlington configuration is to increase current gain and thus allow a source with low current sourcing capability to drive large currents.

Comment: @Peter-did you ever design a transistor gain stage assuming a zero input resistance at the base? Note that the BJT is  neither a current amplifier nor a "transresistance" amplifier (as mentioned by you) - it works as a transconductance amplifier (voltage in and current out). All design rules are based on this! By the way: The meaning of your last sentence ("low current sourcing") is identical to my claim: Large input resistance. Therefore, I do not understand your first sentence which suggest to assume zero input resistance.How do you solve this contradiction?

Comment: @LvW: Imagine you apply a 5V source with essentially zero output resistance to the base pin of an NPN transistor in common emitter configuration. What happens? From the Ebers-Moll model, it's pretty obvious that the base-emitter junction becomes forward biased and a large current flows from the supply to ground via the B-E junction. That's why it's a little dangerous to treat the base-emitter junction merely an equivalent resistance: this is only true under narrow bias conditions. A BJT is fundamentally a current-controlled device, not a voltage-controlled one.

Comment: @Peter...sorry to say: The last sentence is simply wrong. Do you know a single proof for this claim? Do you need some proofs for voltage-control? On the other hand - it is not my main task to teach you....(Did you ever hear about the -2mV/K tempco which was not only measured but calculated based on carrier physics?)

Comment: @LvW Yes, the temperature coefficient falls out of semiconductor physics which explains the behavior of the junction - where did I say otherwise? You *are* aware that people do use transistors outside the small-signal amplifier regime? They make handy switches, too. Just because you can linearize the device behavior around a fixed base bias voltage which allows you to assume transconductance operation does not mean this generalizes to large signal behavior!

Comment: @LvW Just take one look at the Ebers-Moll model, which shows that under large-signal conditions, a BJT is current controlled: In forward active, you inject a current of Ib at the base, you get Ic = Ib\*h_fe. If you voltage-drive the base rather than current-drive it, the output still depends on the base-to-emitter *current* which will be a function of the bias voltage on the base and the Shockley diode equation. Yes, you can consider that a "resistance" if you guarantee that the change in V_be isn't large - but this ignores the large-signal perspective.

Comment: @Peter...do you realize that you have nothing else than a claim and the equation Ic=beta*Ib -? Such an equation never can tell you something about cause and effect. It is just a misinterpretation of Ib=Ic/beta. Did you think about the -2mV/K ? Do you how a current mirror works? Do you know how an emitter resistor works (VOLTAGE feedback)? Do you realize that beta has no influence on voltage gain? Which curve are you using for explaining the difference between class-A and class-B operation? Even the EARLY effect can only be explained using the Voltage (E-field) across the depletion area.

Comment: Peter.....try to consult some good papers from Berkeley or Stanford or the MIT  or...(and dont rely on wikipedia or some other "obscure" knowledge sources).

Comment: look here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/143503/npn-bjt-base-emitter-resistance-is-effectively-zero

Comment: Oof. Now we're just getting pedantic. If you take the "voltage drives the current and thus this is voltage controlled" view, literally every device in the universe is "voltage controlled." Yes, I know how a transistor works internally. It's irrelevant to the discussion at hand. Do you intend to keep track of every charge carrier in the silicon in your head? Of course not. We have macroscopic models to abstract the behavior of complex phenomena at every level of engineering, and by definition these models must be simplifications, otherwise it would be pointless for them to exist.

Comment: In the case of the abstract macroscale models we have for BJT behavior in-circuit, it is *far* more intuitive to treat the BJT as a current-controlled device (ie: Ebers-Moll large signal model) for large signal low-frequency operation, *because that's what falls out of the math for the model*. Does it matter that the model actually describes emergent behaviour of charge carriers and fields in silicon? Not at all. As long as we know what the limits are to the model, there is no problem with simplifying.

Comment: So, in summary: it's good to know how a transistor works (that's part of every undergrad EE education). But it's also critically important to learn how to think abstractly and not get too caught up on the fact that our abstractions are merely simplifications. In the common abstractions we use to describe BJT circuit behaviour (Ebers-Moll, Gummel-Poon, etc), it makes far more sense to envision the base current controlling the collector current, even if the truth is subtly more complicated.

Comment: And yes, I am aware that it is certainly possible to operate in an "infinite beta" regime (forward alpha = 1, in which case the collector current will be exponentially proportional to V_be - this is easy to see via inspection of the Ebers-Moll model). My point is, viewing the BJT as a voltage controlled device necessitates dealing with a high degree of nonlinearity, since the collector current will be exponentially related to V_be. For *intuitive* understanding, the current-controlled model makes sense. Note that I'm *not* saying that the voltage viewpoint doesn't have merit in certain cases.

Comment: Peter - with all respect, You do not see my point. The core of your comments is: ".. more intuitive to treat the BJT as current-controlled ", "..makes more sense...", "For intuitive understanding, ...makes sense...". THAT IS NOT THE POINT! And I do not speak about models!! You certainly know the so called "re model" where the transconductance gm=1/re appears as an "intrinsic emitter resistance" - for my opinion a catastrophic misconception....it may be helpful for deriving and applying formulas but it does not help at all to understand whats going on between input and output (4-pole).

Comment: No - my only point is to avoid severs contradictions which always will confuse students (my experience), I gave you some examples for circuits, observations and typical BJT parameters which can be explained only with voltage control. And at the same time, some people and some books speak about current control (WITHOUT ANY PROOF !), just a claim - based on the relationship IB=IC/B. I cannot understand why we should live with such a contradiction. In each electronic lesson, students hear about the diode characterisic - and you see a problem due to "a  high degree of nonlinearity".

Answer (score 3):

I think your question has too many questions. So I'll answer what I'm motivated to answer. Also, you don't write much at all about the context for these questions. And that's important in allowing me to focus what I say. So I will be somewhat terse, as well, in reply because you've not motivated more from me. I hope I strike a balance you find acceptable.

> why do we use darlington pair?

The \$\beta\$ relationship between collector current and the required recombination base current can present an unacceptable load on the driver. In some of these situations, it's acceptable to simply use a second BJT to reduce that load. For example:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTBayx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

On the left, the circuit is attempting to use just a single BJT for a switch. But to achieve that, it needs to guarantee about \$80\:\text{mA}\$ as the base current to make sure that \$Q_1\$ is saturated. (\$\beta_1\approx 10\$.) But most I/O pins from an MCU cannot handle that much current. So the left circuit simply won't work.

On the right, \$Q_2\$ has been added in order to provide additional support. Here, \$Q_1\$ is not saturated (it's collector is about \$600\:\text{mV}\$ higher than before, which may be an issue but probably isn't), so it's \$\beta\$ value is likely much higher. Let's call it \$\beta_1=80\$, as it is in active mode and we are using a higher current BJT here. But \$Q_2\$ here is highly saturated, so again it's \$\beta_2\approx 10\$. But \$Q_2\$ only needs to supply about \$\frac{800\:\text{mA}}{\beta_1=80}\approx 10\:\text{mA}\$ through its collector to the base of \$Q_1\$. So \$Q_2\$'s base (it's saturated, so \$\beta_2\approx 10\$) requires only \$\frac{80\:\text{mA}}{\beta_2=10}\approx 1\:\text{mA}\$. This much current can be supplied by most MCU I/O pins. So the right side circuit may very likely work, satisfactorily. The only question is that the combined collector voltage is a little higher, so there may (or may not) be a new problem. (It depends on the type of the load and what it actually requires.)

> and I've heard that we don't use it as common base. why is that?

The common base configuration has low input impedance and the base is usually connected to a voltage source or else a capacitor of sufficient size that it acts sufficiently close to voltage source. Reducing base recombination current just doesn't arise as an important factor in these cases.

There are other downsides (and also cases where a Darlington actually is used in the common base configuration.) But the bottom line is that common base configurations have priorities that aren't solved by a Darlington arrangement and, in fact, are often more complicated by using one.

> why don't we just develop a bjt with high beta value instead of using
>   this structure?

There are high beta value BJTs. For example, the [DSC2A01](https://industrial.panasonic.com/content/data/SC/ds/ds4/DSC2A01_E.pdf) is a single BJT with a fairly high \$\beta\$ value.

There are practical limitations. For example, making the base narrower increases \$\beta\$ because there is a smaller chance for recombination during transit from collector to emitter. But doing so also worsens the Early Effect.

---

I'm stopping at this point. As I said, you've piled a lot of questions together and I've decided to take as many that are directly related to each other as I feel I could. The remaining ones are really part of a different topic.

Answer (score 1):

**1. Why do we use Darlington pair?**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBtoRW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The Darlington pair can be seen as a new single transistor with modified parameters.

- The dynamic input resistance is rather high: hie,D=2*hie,1
- The "beta-factor" (hfe)  is large: hfe,D=hfe,1*hfe,2
- The gain (transconductance) is reduced: gm,D=0.5*gm,2 .

**Example**:

Common emitter gain stage with gain A=-100 (collector resistance Rc=1k, no negative signal feedback )

Transistors: hfe,1=100 and hfe,2=50 ;

Reqired transconductance: gm,D=0.1 A/V (A=-gm,D*Rc=-0.1*1000=-100) ;

Q2: gm,2=2*gm,D=0.2A/V and Ic,2=VT*gm,2=5mA;

Q1: Ic1=Ic,2/hfe,2=0.1mA and gm,1=4mA/V and hie,1=hfe,1/gm,1=25 kOhm :

**Darlington input resistance** : hie,D=2*hie,1=**50 kOhm**

**Comparison** with a **single transistor stage** (hfe=100; same gain A=-100):

Required transconductance (as before): gm=0.1 A/V

**Input resistance**: hie=hfe/gm=100/0.1=**1 kOhm** .

**Result**: For the same gain (A=-100) the input resistance at the base node of the Darlington combination is much larger if compared with a single transistor (Example: Factor 50). This the most important property of the Darlington compound transistor.